# ViewPager Screen Slides strange artifacts

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-viewpager, android

I followed the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) from Android dev site for my GridView fragment photo app (photos layout in gridview, when clicked a photo will start slideable fullscreen).

I got this strange artifact where every photo when slided left/right leaves a trail of itself, this showed most obviously when the previous photo is bigger than the next.

*Note: this is not phone related issue.

Screenshot below:

[image: ViewPager artifact]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally figured out the culprit: I was using this Android theme for the fullscreen ViewPager framelayout.

```
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>
```

Use this instead for it to work correctly:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```